# Columns ordering in Django's model

Tags: django, django-models

So, I am wondering that how to define the order of the columns in Model so that when Django does forward engineering to generate database, the order of columns in the physical database table can be determined by the Model itself?

Currently some of my model classes inhering from other model class, so the derived model class always put the columns from the parent class first, but I want to control that.

Thanks

Comment: ever found a workaround for this? While calling functions in pgsql that use ROWTYPE variables as parameter I need to serialize the model in the correct column order and I cannot find a solution for this (currently trying to understand django's MigrationAutoDetector class)

Answer (score 8):

On Django 1.8 this worked for me:

- run `./manage.py makemigrations`
- edit the migration
- reorder the `fields` list on `migrations.CreateModel`.

I did not test this with inheritance though.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no built-in way to do this in Django.

I seem to remember a django-dev thread/ticket that discussed this, but I can't see to find it at the moment. I'll update this if I find it (and welcome anyone else to if they do.)

There's probably a way to hack this into the core if you really need it that bad.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I realized that probably it is not that simple to implement, because the migration seems a little bit hard to adjust the order of columns.

Comment: Would be simple enough to do with a kwarg like `after="id"`

Answer (score 0):

You could run [`django-admin.py sql`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#sql-appname-appname) which will print the SQL that creates the table for one or all apps, adjust the SQL to fit your needs and run it manually in some db shell of your choice!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to control the order of the fields in the database or just the way they are presented to the users? If the latter, there other options. For example, in the admin you can control the order of fields with [fieldsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) or [fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields).

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing and YES, it's important to control the order of the fields in the database. Why? For readability. Not only when altering tables and such, but when drawing out data models as well. I have a TraceModel meta class that automatically provides created_on, created_by, edited_on and edited_by fields, but they always show up at the top of each table and that is NOT intuitive!